# Not being able to get interface to work

Tags: solidity, remix, interfaces, external-function

I have been trying to get a basic interface working on remix, but havent managed to. Did read a few examples but I must still be making some mistake.

Trying to interact with this contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.4;

    contract Staker {
      bool public openForWithdraw = false; 
}
```

I am just trying to get the global variable but I am getting no ouputs from the transaction, this is my contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

 interface Staker { 
   function openForWithdraw() external view returns(bool);
 }


 contract test {
    address contractAddress = 0xb9......; 
    Staker staker = Staker(contractAddress);


    function test1() public returns(bool){
      bool result = staker.openForWithdraw();
      return result;
    }
 }
```

As I understand I am not supposed to deploy the interface? only the "test" contract.

Answer (score 1):

It was a small simple mistake, to be able to see the output it was necessary to modify the function:

```
function test1() public **view** returns(bool){
      bool result = staker.openForWithdraw();
      return result;
    }
```